# Spring reading request body twice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging

In spring I have a controller with an endpoint like so:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public OutputStuff createStuff(@RequestBody Stuff stuff) {
    //my logic here
}
```

This way if doing a POST on this endpoint, the JSON in request body will be automatically deserialized to my model (`Stuff`). The problem is, I just got a requirement to log the raw JSON as it is coming in! I tried different approaches.

1. Inject `HttpServletRequest` into `createStuff`, read the body there and log:

Code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public OutputStuff createStuff(@RequestBody Stuff stuff, HttpServletRequest req) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    req.getReader().getLines().forEach(line -> {
        sb.append(line);
    });
    //log sb.toString();
    //my logic here
}
```

The problem with this is that by the time I execute this, the reader's InputStream would have already been executed to deserialize JSON into `Stuff`. So I will get an error because I can't read the same input stream twice.

2. Use custom `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` that would log raw JSON before the actual handler is called.

Code (part of it):

```
public class RawRequestLoggerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        req.getReader().getLines().forEach(line -> {
            sb.append(line);
        });
        //log sb.toString();

        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem with this tho is, that by the time the deserialization to `stuff` happens, the InputStream from the request would have been read already! So I would get an exception again.

3. Another option I considered, but not implemented yet, would be somehow forcing Spring to use my custom implementation of `HttpServletRequest` that would cache the input stream and allow multiple read of it. I have no idea if this is doable tho and I can't find any documentation or examples of that!
4. Yet another option would be not to read `Stuff` on my endpoint, but rather read the request body as `String`, log it and then deserialize it to `Stuff` using `ObjectMapper` or something like that. I do not like this idea either tho.

Are there better solutions, that I did not mention and/or am not aware of? I would appreciate help. I am using the latest release of SpringBoot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As referenced in this post: [How to Log HttpRequest and HttpResponse in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905296/how-to-log-httprequest-and-httpresponse-in-a-file), spring provides the AbstractRequestLoggingFilter you can use to log the request.

AbstractRequestLoggingFilter API Docs, [found here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, I will give it a go!

Comment: Yes, we did in fact go with the Logging Filter, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

To [read the request body multiple times](http://www.javabyexamples.com/read-request-body-multiple-times-using-spring-mvc/), we must cache the initial payload. Because once the original *InputStream* is consumed we can't read it again.

Firstly, Spring MVC provides the *ContentCachingRequestWrapper* class which stores the original content. So we can retrieve the body multiple times calling the *getContentAsByteArray()* method.

So in your case, you can make use of this class in a Filter:

```
@Component
public class CachingRequestBodyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest currentRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(currentRequest);
        // Other details

        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can register *CommonsRequestLoggingFilter* in your application. This filter uses *ContentCachingRequestWrapper* behind the scenes and is designed for [logging the requests](http://www.javabyexamples.com/request-logging-using-spring-mvc/).

Comment: ContentCachingRequestWrapper only works when you use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as content type. If you uses "application/json" as content type, you have to implement your own wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, the challenge still exists to this day, so maybe following solution will be useful to someone, depending on your particular use case.

You might declare your method to receive a request that is parsed and validated according to some model, and additionally you can declare another parameter that will receive a map with all the properties.

Here's a kotlin example:

```kotlin
@PostMapping
fun myAction(
    @RequestParam body: Map<String, String?>,
    @RequestBody @Valid @ModelAttribute request: MyRequestDTO,
    bindingResult: BindingResult
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I also tried to do that in Spring but i could not find way to pass my custom http request to chain so what did was,i have written traditional j2ee filter in that i have passed my custom http request to chain that is it then onward i can read http request more than once

Check this example http://www.myjavarecipes.com/how-to-read-post-request-data-twice-in-spring/