# Spring Security: deserialize request body twice (oauth2 processing)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

This question is a result of some work I'm doing with the Spring Security Oauth2 library. I've set up an oauth2 authorization server and an oauth2 resource server, the latter of which is meant to authorize based on access tokens.

The problem is that normally access tokens are passed in a header, but the big client we're setting this up for wants to pass the access token in a JSON request body. There's an interface you can use to set up custom access token extraction, but it looks like this:

```
public interface TokenExtractor {

/**
 * Extract a token value from an incoming request without authentication.
 * 
 * @param request the current ServletRequest
 * @return an authentication token whose principal is an access token (or null if there is none)
 */
Authentication extract(HttpServletRequest request);
}
```

So, as best I can tell, all I have access to is the raw HTTPServletRequest, from which I need to deserialize the request and extract the access token.

Further complicating things, though, is the fact that the request body also contains other parameters needed for processing, so I want to deserialize it to a DTO class that I pass into my controller, something like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/oauth/someresource")
@Transactional
public Map<String, String> resource(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails,
                                     @RequestBody ClientRequestDto clientRequestDto) {
// Do some processing based on the request dto
}
```

I tried manually deserializing the request in the token extractor, but then I get an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request".

I was brainstorming a few possible solutions that I could research, and so far I've come up with:

1. find a way to reset the input stream
2. deserialize the object in the Token Extractor, attach it to the raw request object, and just access the raw request object in my controller instead of using @RequestBody
3. like 2, but find a way to add a custom deserializer that fetches the object attached to the raw request instead of processing the request's input stream.

Anyways, those are just some thoughts, if anyone has any ideas in terms of an elegant way of solving this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: I did find this question which is similar: [Spring reading request body twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763922/spring-reading-request-body-twice), and the last answer did have one possible solution (creating a decorator request class that allows multiple input stream reads and creating a filter early on in the filter chain that wraps the HttpServletRequest). It seems workable, but a little heavy duty, so I'll leave this up to see if anyone has any other ideas as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up finding yet another question that addressed this issue that I didn't see before posting ([How can I read request body multiple times in Spring 'HandlerMethodArgumentResolver'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804205/how-can-i-read-request-body-multiple-times-in-spring-handlermethodargumentresol)). That one also suggested creating a decorator around the HttpServletRequest, so I adapted the info from http://www.myjavarecipes.com/how-to-read-post-request-data-twice-in-spring/, adding a protection against large requests.

Here's what I came up with, in case anyone has any feedback:

```
public class MultiReadHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
// We include a max byte size to protect against malicious requests, since this all has to be read into memory
public static final Integer MAX_BYTE_SIZE = 1_048_576; // 1 MB

private String _body;

public MultiReadHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    _body = "";

    InputStream bounded = new BoundedInputStream(request.getInputStream(), MAX_BYTE_SIZE);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bounded));

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        _body += line;
    }
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws       IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(_body.getBytes());

    return new ServletInputStream() {
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return byteArrayInputStream.available() == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {

        }
    };
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
}
}
```

I used the following configuration:

```
    @Bean
FilterRegistrationBean multiReadFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    MultiReadRequestFilter multiReadRequestFilter = new MultiReadRequestFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(multiReadRequestFilter);
    registrationBean.setOrder(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER - 2);
    registrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Sets.newHashSet("/path/here"));
    return registrationBean;
}
```