# Prevent Jersey from closing InputStream when injecting parameters?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a `Factory<T>` that uses the `InputStream` from `ContainerRequestContext` to create `T`. In my factory I mark and reset the `InputStream` so that Jersey can then inject the body into the endpoint parameter. This works fine

**problem**: if I swap the ordering of these parameters (`String body` first, then `@Context T t`) it breaks. Jersey has closed the `InputStream` before my `Factory<T>` tries to read from the InputStream.

`Factory<T>`:

```java
@Override
public T provide() {
    InputStream inputStream = containerRequestContext.getEntityStream();
    inputStream.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    T t = new T(inputStream);

    inputStream.reset();
    return t;
}
```

`ResourceConfig` endpoint (works):

```java
@POST
public Response getBodyDouble(@Context T t, String body) {}
```

`ResourceConfig` endpoint (creating T fails):

```java
@POST
public Response getBodyDouble(String body, @Context T t) {}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity input stream has already been closed.
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.ensureNotClosed(EntityInputStream.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.getEntityStream(InboundMessageContext.java:762)
        at com.-.TFactory.provide(TFactory.java:xx)
```

Is there a way to prevent Jersey from closing the InputStream when it injects the body? Or some way to re-open it? Thanks

Comment: Even if Jersey didn't close the input stream, it would already have **consumed** the stream, so preventing close will not make the code work anyway. Why would you need the body twice anyway? If you really do, 1) create `t` from `body`, 2) create `body` from `t`, 3) accept a `byte[]` and create both from it, 4) accept `InputStream` and create both from it, or 5) ... *many other ways to do it*

Comment: Right. But potentially an unclosed stream could be reset or wrapped so that downstream consumers could use it.

Comment: I'm writing a wrapper library, so the use-case is just me wanting to keep the second endpoint contract safe :) It's a scary error, and it's not obvious (except for people who know jersey) that the parameter ordering would fix the problem

Comment: What would fix the problem is not asking Jersey for the request body twice. Otherwise see [Logging HttpRequest parameters and request body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6322362/5221149) or [Spring REST service: retrieving JSON from Request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10457963/5221149) or any other [similar question](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+request+body+logger).

Comment: There are _a lot_ of use cases where you would want access to the body outside of the resource method.

Comment: One way would be to force Jersey to buffer the entity. If you created a filter that casted the ContainerRequestContext to ContainerRequest, you could call cr.bufferEntity(). That's just one solution I can think of. Not sure if it is the _best_ though.